# Problema con un DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

estoy aprendiendo `asp.net mvc` y me ha surgido un problema al momento de editar, crear o eliminar un dato de la base de datos.

Me muestra el siguiente error pero no sé como corregirlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]